# Path of home directory in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using Urlrewrite iis module. My virtual path: localhost/news/example-content.html

`<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>` => `localhost/news/js/jquery.min.js`

`<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>` => `localhost/news/../js/jquery.min.js`

How can i fix it?

Comment: What do you want to fix?

Comment: I want localhost/js/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Server.MapPath** method:

```
<script src='<%=Server.MapPath("/~js/jquery.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I am useing Mozilla Firefox and look the network but css and js don't show

Answer (score 0):

a solution can be :

```
<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/jquery.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

directly in aspx page.

Comment: Status Code : 304 Not modifed

Comment: possible come from IIS

Comment: This is goto localhost/js/jquery.js but Mozilla Network Status gets the 304 Not Modified error all item and don't show

Answer (score 0):

You can put the absolute path like below

```
<script src="http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that when you host the site you can put the site name instead of `localhost`

Comment: I will publish this project, change all localhost?